# How to programatically close the file "save" window in flex?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4.5, alivepdf

I am using alivePDF to generate pdfs from my flex application. When I click on the save pdf button on my flex application, a "save as" window pops up which allows me to browse to the location where I want to save the pdf file. Its the same window that pops up when we try to save any file in notepad, word, etc. I want to programatically close this window if the user is idle for a given amount of time. The code that I am using for saving the pdf is as follows.

```
var file:FileReference = new FileReference();
        var genPdf:PDF = new PDF();
        genPdf = generatePDF(target, generateXML,str);
        file.save(genPdf.save(Method.LOCAL), 'graph.pdf');
```

Answer (score 2):

This can't be done as it would violate flash's security model, ie it would allow something to be saved to the hd without the user's knowledge/permission.